# Почему DataGrid такой медленный, или как придать приличный вид GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

Пишу проект на **WPF**. На одном из `View` необходимо выводить клиенту довольно большой по объему список объектов в виде таблицы. Идеально для этого подошёл бы `DataGrid`. Я не очень-то люблю *"изобретать велосипеды"*, поэтому нашёл множество уже готовых решений (те же контролы от *Syncfusion*). Я уж было очень сильно обрадовался, однако столкнулся с серьёзной проблемой: привязывая коллекцию большого объёма (более сотни объектов) к `DataGrid`, процесс рендеринга самого контрола сильно затягивается (и это при том, что, унаследовавшись `ObservableCollection`, я добавил метод `AddRange()`, чтобы при добавлении каждого объекта не вызывалось событие интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Если добавлять *200-300* объектов в коллекцию за раз и привязать их к `DataGrid`, процесс затянется уж очень надолго и приложение может вовсе зависнуть. Получение данных из базы и формирование модельных объектов происходят во вторичном потоке. Думал, что проблема в количестве объектов при их создании, однако, после использования профайлера, я понял, что все тормоза начинаются именно после вызова `AddRange()` на привязанной коллекции. Возможно, проблема в том, что каждый модельный объект реализует *INPC*? И содержит в себе ряд таких же вложенных объектов, также реализующих этот интерфейс?
Как бы там ни было, я попробовал заменить `DataGrid` на `GridView`, и, в принципе, всё стало работать довольно быстро. Однако `GridView` не предоставляет множества преимуществ, которые имеются у `DataGrid` (начиная от элементарной сортировки и заканчивая готовым красивым оформлением). Теперь меня интересует, как придать более или менее приличный вид `GridView`. Например, как придать ему стиль *"Metro"*? 
Или же есть какая-то возможность, чтобы оптимизировать работу `DataGrid`? Ну не верится мне, что на рендеринг сотни модельных объектов уходит так много времени и это так затормаживает **UI**.

**UPDATE:**

*ViewModel:*

```
public class TaskEntitiesListViewModel : StoreUsingViewModel, IPageViewModel
    {
        #region fields
        private TaskEntityModel currentTask;        
        private List<TaskEntityModel> cacheTaskEntityModelList;
        #endregion
        #region ctors
        public TaskEntitiesListViewModel() : base()
        {
            this.cacheTaskEntityModelList = new List<TaskEntityModel>();
            this.TaskEntities = new ObservableCollectionExtended<TaskEntityModel>();           
        }
        #endregion
        #region INPCProperties        
        public ObservableCollectionExtended<TaskEntityModel> TaskEntities { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region eventSubscribers
        [EventSubscription("topic://Authorization/CorrectCredentialsEntered", typeof(OnUserInterface))]
        [EventSubscription("topic://Application/ViewUsual", typeof(OnUserInterface))]        
        public async void InitTaskEntitiesListUsualAsync()
        {            
            if (TaskEntities.Count != 0) TaskEntities.Clear();

            var taskEntitiesListFromDAL = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Store.GetTaskEntityList<TaskDAL>(t => t.Owner, t => t.Creator, t => t.Base).ToList());

            //wrapping each TaskEntity to TaskEntityModel
            if (cacheTaskEntityModelList.Count != 0) cacheTaskEntityModelList.Clear();
            taskEntitiesListFromDAL.ForEach(t => cacheTaskEntityModelList.Add(new TaskEntityModel(t)));

            TaskEntities.AddRange(cacheTaskEntityModelList.Where(t => t.IsOver == false).Take(100).ToList()); 
        }
        #endregion
        #region IPageViewModel
        public string Name { get { return "TaskEntitiesList"; } }
        #endregion
        #region BaseViewModel
        public override void OnDataChangedGlobalEvent()
        {
            InitTaskEntitiesListUsualAsync();
        }
        #endregion        
    }
```

*Код коллекции:*

```
public class ObservableCollectionExtended<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool _suppressNotification = false;
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

        _suppressNotification = true;

        foreach (T item in list)
            Add(item);

        _suppressNotification = false;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ClearRange()
    {
        _suppressNotification = true;

        ClearItems();

        _suppressNotification = false;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Во вьюшке в качестве `ItemsSource` для `DataGrid` используется `public ObservableCollectionExtended<TaskEntityModel> TaskEntities { get; set; }`

**UPDATE 2**

*код View:*

```
<UserControl x:Class="DesktopWPFApplication.Views.TaskEntitiesListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesktopWPFApplication.Views"
             xmlns:params="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium/params"
             xmlns:extra="http://schemas.extra.com/ui"
             xmlns:metro="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium"             
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DesktopWPFApplication.Core.ViewModels;assembly=DesktopWPFApplication.Core"
             xmlns:infrastructure="clr-namespace:DesktopWPFApplication.Core.Infrastructure;assembly=DesktopWPFApplication.Core"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:TaskEntitiesListViewModel}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
        <infrastructure:BooleanToColorBrushConverter x:Key="BoolToColor"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        <DataGrid  
                      ItemsSource="{Binding TaskEntities, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False, IsAsync=True}" 
                      EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="False"
                      MaxWidth="2560" 
                      MaxHeight="1600">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <extra:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop1,  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
                <extra:DataGridDateColumn Binding="{Binding DateProp1,  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
                <extra:DataGridDateColumn Binding="{Binding DateProp2,  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
                <extra:DataGridDateColumn Binding="{Binding DateProp3,  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
                <extra:DataGridDateColumn Binding="{Binding DateProp4,  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
                <extra:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop2, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
                <extra:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop3, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
                <extra:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop4, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
                <extra:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop5, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UPDATE 3**
*Model:*

```
   public class TaskEntityModel : BaseModel
    {
        #region fields
        private string prop1;
        private string prop2;
        private string prop3;
        private string prop4;
        private string prop5;
        private DateTime dateProp1;
        private DateTime dateProp2;
        private DateTime dateProp3;
        private DateTime dateProp4;     
        #endregion
        #region ctors 
        public TaskEntityModel(TaskEntity taskEntity) : base(taskEntity)
        {
            //filling fields            
        }        
        #endregion
        #region INPCProperties       

        public string Prop1
        {
            get { return prop1; }
            set
            {
                if (value != prop1)
                {
                    prop1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Prop1");
                }
            }
        }

        public DateTime DateProp1
        {
            get
            {
                if (dateProp1 == null)
                    dateProp1 = DateTime.Now;
                return dateProp1;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != dateProp1)
                {
                    dateProp1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DateProp1");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DateProp2");
                }
            }
        }
        //and so on

        #endregion        
    }

    public abstract class BaseModel : ObservableObject 
    {
        #region fields
        protected int ID;
        #endregion
        public int UID
        {
            get { return ID; }
            set
            {
                if(value != ID)
                {
                    ID = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("UID");
                }
            }
        }
        public BaseModel() { }
        public BaseModel(BaseEntity baseEntity)
        {
            if(baseEntity != null)
            { 
            this.ID = baseEntity.ID;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если проблема сводится к внешнему виду, то можно глянуть в сторону DevExpress (он вообще платный, но... (сами продолжите))

Comment: А как реализован ваш `AddRange`? Может, проблема в нём?

Comment: Код коллекции, вьюхи и вьюмодели (или что там у вас вместо нее) в студию. А еще лучше готовый минимально вопроизводимый пример, который можно скачать.

Comment: @VladD, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @andreycha, обновил вопрос.

Comment: А сколько у вас объектов всего в коллекции?

Comment: @VladD от 200 до 1000. Но количество объектов в коллекции никак не влияет на то, как долго отображается контрол. Я ведь в любом случае привязываю не более сотни объектов к самому DataGrid.

Comment: @klutch1991: Хм. Это мало, даже очень мало. Тормозить не должно. Тогда давайте смотреть на View. И ещё, покажите `TaskEntityModel`. `ObservableCollection` у вас выглядит правильно.

Comment: Во вьюхе на первый взгляд ничего подозрительного, дайте код `TaskEntityModel`.

Comment: Автогенерацию колонок пробовали включить? По идее она работает быстрее, чем вручную заданные колонки.

Comment: @andreycha, на самом деле Автогенерация мне не совсем подходит. Во-первых: свойств гораздо больше в модели, чем нужно вывести, а во-вторых: некоторые колонки нужно стилизовать по-особенному

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас первая привязка проходит с нормальной скоростью, а добавление элементов вызывает тормоза, то вы неправильно работаете с коллекцией. Большие изменения должны происходить пакетно, а единственное уведомление должно быть `new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)`. Как вариант, если не писать свою коллекцию, то можно менять экземпляр коллекции с соответствующим уведомлением. А вот реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` на самой коллекции интересует `ItemsControl` куда меньше.

<s>По коду коллекции: у вас ошибка в коде `AddRange`. Внутри метода вы вызываете публичный метод `Add`, которому глубоко наплевать на ваш флаг `_suppressNotification` и который рассылает всю пачку уведомлений каждый раз. Вам надо вызывать защищённый метод `InsertItem`. Или можете опуститься на уровень ниже и работать напрямую со свойством `Items`, но тогда на вашей совести будут вызовы `OnPropertyChanged` для `Count` и `Item[]`, а также вызов `CheckReentrancy`.</s>

Хм. Нет. Не должно быть наплевать. Впрочем, вы перекрывате только `OnCollectionChanged`. Возможно, `OnPropertyChanged` тоже влияет.

Comment: @klutch1991 Запустите под мерялкой производительности и посмотрите, что происходит: какой метод жрёт время, какие методы сколько раз вызываются и прочее.

Comment: Все тормоза начинаются при вызове AddRange() на коллекции, привязанной к контролу.

Comment: @klutch1991 Этой информации мало, и она и так очевидна. Нужно узнать, что происходит потом: какие методы на каком уровне сколько времени отнимают и почему.

Comment: OnPropertyChanged здесь вряд ли влияет на что-то, поскольку метод `Add()`, вызываемый в `AddRange()` принадлежит классу `Collection<T>` и не перегружен в `ObservableCollection<T>`. При этом `Collection<T>` не реализует INPC, следовательно при добавлении каждого из элементов, `OnPropertyChanged` не вызывается. А флаг `_suppressNotification` блокирует `OnCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Смотрел под профайлером - все тормоза появляются ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО в процессе рендеринга самого контрола. Ни один метод из кода c# не занимает много времени.

Comment: @klutch1991 Метод `Add` вызывает виртуальный защищённый `InsertItem`, который очень даже перегружен в `ObservableCollection<>` и кидает два `PropertyChanged` и один `CollectionChanged`. Вы перекрываете только второй. В общем, либо сделайте так, чтобы бросался только один `Reset`, либо забиндитесь сразу на заполненную коллекцию, либо меняйте экземпляр коллекции — нужно исключить из рассмотрения проблему с добавлением.

Comment: @klutch1991 ну что, попробовали? Discord дело говорит.